# How to send a variable from python file to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been creating a desktop application using pyqt5. In my application, there is a tab widget and inside that tab widget, there is a "start" button. So, after clicking that button a list of latitudes and longitudes is generated.

I want to send this list to a javascript file(I am using leaflet.js to create a map), such that I can make a map using this information. How can I send this list to a javascript file from my python application?

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Delivering & Tracking'
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.showFullScreen()

class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        #Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.map_tab = Maps()

        self.tabs.resize(300,200)

        self.tabs.addTab(self.map_tab,QIcon("./icons and images/tab_map.png"), ('Map'))

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class Maps(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.startButton()

    def startButton(self):
        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.move(655, 415)
        button.clicked.connect(self.map)

        self.show()

    def map(self):
        #A list is generated in this function.
        latlon = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The latlon list which is generated inside the map function, I want to send list to a javascript file, such that I can use it to a map.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write the list to a file of whatever format makes the most sense, and then read from that file with the javascript that you're using!

For example (to write):

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
    for coord in latlon:
        f.write(coord + "\n")
```

For example (to read, I personally don't know javascript so this might be a bad solution):

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("test.txt", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: @AloysiusSamuel No problem, if you feel that this solved your issue, please mark this as the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before but it seems from https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/09/13/embedding-a-leaflet-map-in-a-qt-application/ that you can have a javascript file on the server and simply inject the coordinates into it before evaluating the script in the frame.

If your javascript file has the following format:

```
// map_source.js
// a lot of javascript
map.panTo(new L.LatLng($lat$, $long$));
// more javascript
// file end
```

Then you can inject a longitude and latitude in the following way:

```
def map(self):
    #A list is generated in this function.
    latlon = [latitude_value, longitude_value]
    with open('map_source.js', 'r') as f:
        lines = '<my custom newline>'.join(f.readlines())

    # substitute latitude
    lines = lines.replace('$lat$',str(latlon[0]))
    # substitute longitude
    lines = lines.replace('$long$',str(latlon[1]))
    # Now write the file back
    with open('map_source.js', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(lines.split('<my custom newline>'))
```